# How to truncate text to fit page in one line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a `td` like this:

```
<td><%= thing.message %></td>
```

If the message is long, it spans over multiple lines. I want it to truncate at the end of the page on the first line. I can use `truncate`, but I have to pick a length, which depends on the size of the screen. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you should use `text-overflow` [CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

**Update**

If you don't want to wrap text to several lines you should specify `white-space: nowrap;` property too. [This example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow?v=example) show situation described in your question. (Thank you @sawa)

Comment: You should write the value for it to make the answer useful. Doesn't it also need `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: Would it be possible to change the link to the [MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) rather than the toxically bad [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/)?

Comment: I tried using text-overflow, i put an id in the td and the css in the stylesheet; now the text is one line that makes the page really wide, not sure why...

Comment: Just put your text inside of `div` and apply these CSS properties to this `div`: `<td><div id="your-id-here"><%= thing.message %></div></td>`

Comment: @sawa That link I have there explains more, but mostly it's that the site is dangerously out of date and promotes hazardously bad practices. The MDN site is extremely high quality and is always up to date.